# How to provide range to RNG function in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to programming and I got stucked with Guessing Game tutorial exercise. I'm trying to provide a range to the RNG function but I'm probably doing it wrong. I read the whole [documentation](https://rust-random.github.io/book/intro.html) but I didn't find a solution to my issue.

The idea is very simple :

- Player choose a difficulty level
- Each difficulty level matches a range
- RNG function pick a number within this range

Here is the code I wrote :

```
use rand::Rng;
fn main() {

println!("\nChoississez votre niveau de difficulté\n
        A- Facile\n
        B- Normale\n
        C- Difficile\n");

let difficulte: String = read!();

let intervalle = match difficulte.as_str() {
    "A" => 1..=10,
    "B" => 1..=100,
    "C" => 1..=1000,
    _ => 1..=10000,
};

println!("\nDécouvrez un nombre entre {} et {}", intervalle.start(), intervalle.end());

let secret_number= rand::thread_rng().gen_range(intervalle.start()..intervalle.end());

println!("secret number {}", secret_number);

}
```

I get an error for that line (everything after gen.range) :

```
let secret_number= rand::thread_rng().gen_range(intervalle.start()..intervalle.end());
```

Here is the error :

> the trait bound `&{integer}: rand::distributions::uniform::SampleUniform` is not satisfied

> the trait `rand::distributions::uniform::SampleUniform` is not implemented for `&{integer}`

If I change intervalle.start() and intervalle.end() by actual numbers (1 and 100 for example) everything is working fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `start` and `end` methods return references and not values, i.e. a `&i32` and not a `i32`. You could fix this by just dereferencing the return values:

```rust
let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(*intervalle.start()..*intervalle.end());
//                                               ^                    ^
```

`*` is the dereferencing operator.

Instead of constructing a range and storing it in `intervalle` just to use that range's bounds to construct another range, though, you can just pass `intervalle` to `gen_range` directly!

```rust
let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(intervalle);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation ! I understand my mistake now. And thank you for the solution as well. I made things overly complicated.